# (Realtek TL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter) Bluetooth not working

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, 17.04, realtek

I Have a HP 250 G4 Laptop with a realtek TL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter and I fixed the wifi signal issue with another post, However, Whenever I try to enable bluetooth with "blueman" and other utilities nothing happens. here is the adapter info a script i found gave me:

```
Ubuntu Pastebin


########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 10 Jun 2017 16:04 BST +0100

Booted last: 10 Jun 2017 00:00 BST +0100

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 22 17:43:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, persistent, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:80c1]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
rtl8723be              90112  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              782336  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_soc_rt298          36864  0
snd_soc_rt286          36864  0
snd_soc_rl6347a        16384  2 snd_soc_rt298,snd_soc_rt286
snd_soc_core          233472  3 snd_soc_ssm4567,snd_soc_rt298,snd_soc_rt286
snd_pcm               102400  8 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_rt298,snd_soc_rt286,snd_soc_core
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1031     1  0 15:48 ?        00:00:07 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp13s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.10.0-22-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:0d:00.0/net/wlp13s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp13s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --   
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = HP-250-G4
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       expiry = 1497193247
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                        
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp7s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:07:00.0/net/enp7s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########


[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto



##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

global
country GB: DFS-ETSI


##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp7s0    no frequency information.

wlp13s0   13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp7s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)


##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     8A4042E8F447BFEE8F45BA5
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
 (int)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     B06F4AE01E9561133D82E7E
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     B93F82B28F7945C22514E4D
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     884DE3F31278351A45DA409
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-22-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     309C9ACED540FCAA1DE7422
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-22-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D77C8F93375950F3BA95B16
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
ant_sel: 0
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################
```